# Generate HTML in custom directive and $compile in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

PLUNKER: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/IQpGhinzsHUUqmwbHFmQ?p=preview

I am trying to create a form that reads from some JSON and creates the relevant view. Each set of questions are in their own step. I am having trouble getting access to each `input` to validate it using AngularJS.

How do I get access to the `answers` model that is created in the `forEach` loop?

HTML:

```
    <form ng-app="MyApp" novalidate >
        <section class="question step " ng-controller="StepController">

            <div class="step-contents">
                {{title}}

                <step-contents content="content" ></step-contents>
            </div>
            <button >Prev</button>
            <button ng-click="nextStep(content)">Next</button>
        </section>
    </form>
```

My AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('StepController', function($scope) {

    $scope.index = 0;

    $scope.nextStep = function() {

        console.log($scope.answers); // This should be the input data for _THIS_ step only

    }

    $scope.showStep = function() {

        //FOREACH HAPPENS HERE
        // Loops over some JSON to generate the following HTML:
        $scope.title = "Step 1 title";

        var html = '<input type="number"  ng-model="answers.amount" />';
        html += '<input type="text"  ng-model="answers.name" />';
        $scope.content = html;

        //FOREACH ENDS HERE

    }

    $scope.showStep();

});

app.directive('stepContents', function ($compile) {

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){

        element.html(scope.content);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            content: '=',
        },
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a name to your form, and then you can access the form elements with $scope.formName.inputName, which will reference the ngModelController of the input. Check out Angular's documentation for ngFormController and ngModelController for more details.